# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in system.log

Tags: magento-1.9, third-party-module

I am getting System.log errors in below 2 lines :

```
if($result == "" || $result->Shipment->StatusType == 'NF') {

                    $res_error_type = "NF";
                    $res_error = "Incorrect Waybill number or No Information";

                    if($result->Shipment->StatusType) { // error in this line
                        $res_error_type = $result->Shipment->StatusType;
                    }

                    if($result->Shipment->Status) { // error in this line
                        $res_error = $result->Shipment->Status;
                    }
```

**Edit** : full error log :

```
017-09-25T07:57:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): cancel
2017-09-25T07:58:50+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /app/code/community/Bluedart/Shipment/Block/Tracking/Popup.php on line 74
2017-09-25T07:58:50+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in app/code/community/Bluedart/Shipment/Block/Tracking/Popup.php on line 74
2017-09-25T07:58:50+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in app/code/community/Bluedart/Shipment/Block/Tracking/Popup.php on line 78
2017-09-25T07:58:50+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /app/code/community/Bluedart/Shipment/Block/Tracking/Popup.php on line 78
2017-09-25T07:59:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
```

Comment: here is full code : https://pastebin.com/6s4FxBcf

Comment: please update your question with full error log.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy Thanks for suggestion, updated error......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like this.

```
if($result == "" || $result->Shipment->StatusType == 'NF') {

    $res_error_type = "NF";
    $res_error = "Incorrect Waybill number or No Information";

    if ($result && $result->Shipment) {
        if($result->Shipment->StatusType) { // error in this line
            $res_error_type = $result->Shipment->StatusType;
        }
        if($result->Shipment->Status) { // error in this line
            $res_error = $result->Shipment->Status;
        }
    }
```

This will resolve your issue.